# PHP Email Sending Error

Tags: php, sockets, email, pear

I am trying to edit PHP code that sends an email using PEAR. The below code has worked on the company server, but doesn't seem to work on my computer when I am using localhost.

```
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,

        'To' => $to,

            'Subject' => $subject);     



    //Send the Actual Mail

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',

        array ( 'host' => $host,

            'auth' => false,

            'username' => $username,

            'password' => $password));



    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);



    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 

    {

        echo($mail->getMessage());

    }

    else 

    { 

        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!<p>");

    }
```

The items in $headers are defined earlier, don't worry.
The error returned by echo($mail->getMessage()); is as follows:

Failed to connect to localhost:25 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]

I'm on a machine running Ubuntu. Not sure if any other information is needed.

Comment: This is likely because you dont have a mail server on your local machine.

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server running on localhost?  Does that server allow you to use it in this manner?  It would seem the answer to one of these questions is "no."

Comment: Thanks, I have realized that this obviously won't work because of my lack of an SMTP server. However, when attempting to use the real SMTP server of the company with $host = something.com (not really) and a real username and password, it still doesn't work (and gives the same error).

Comment: Maybe try using something like [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) and see if the code submits locally to mailcatcher. Could be other reasons you cant connect to your smtp server from outside of your work. ie firewalls etc